# Uninstall R Markdown in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

How do I go about uninstalling R markdown in Rstudio?

After installing R markdown, plot.conf doesn't seem to work anymore. 
i.e. plot(plot.conf=FALSE...

Comment: Unlikely to be rmarkdown causing this problem. Try restarting Rstudio and post reproducible example here if problems persist.

Comment: @RichardTelford I re-installed the newest version of R and Rstudio. I downloaded the packages: fpp, fpp2, ggplot2, forecast. At the beginning of my code I typed library(fpp). The error I get when I write plot(naive(train, h=h), plot.conf=FALSE) is: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : "plot.conf" is not a graphical parameter

Comment: Sorry the error message is ... `1: In plot.window(xlim, ylim, log, ...) :
  "plot.conf" is not a graphical parameter
2: In title(main = main, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, ...) :
  "plot.conf" is not a graphical parameter
3: In axis(1, ...) : "plot.conf" is not a graphical parameter
4: In axis(2, ...) : "plot.conf" is not a graphical parameter
5: In box(...) : "plot.conf" is not a graphical parameter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
remove.packages('fpp')
remove.packages('rmarkdown')

install.packages('fpp')
install.packages('rmarkdown')
install.packages('survival')
install.packages('forecast')



library(fpp)
library(rmarkdown)
library(survival)
library(forecast)


plot(naive(train, h=h))
```

All you need to do is leave out the plot.conf section and it will run!

Comment: Will this remove dependencies as well?

Comment: It will not because those dependencies will be used for other packages.

Comment: what package are you using for `plot.conf`? I would suggest to uninstall both packages that are dependent of this and the reinstall them

Comment: I'm using the fpp package. So that includes expsmooth, fma, forecast, fpp, lmtest, tseries, and zoo

Comment: no luck :( the problem is that when I start typing plot.conf, the suggestion is not even there (https://ibb.co/hr9rQa) BUT it worked perfectly fine before. the only difference between then and now is that I've installed R Markdown, installed the newest version of R, and uploaded the vars package.

Comment: and you typed `library(fpp)`?

Comment: yes at the very start of my code. that's the only package I referred to.

Comment: Maybe the next additions of packages has the dependency of that function...let me know if that works

Comment: thanks for your help but it's not working. would you perhaps know another way to not display the confidence levels on a plot (seeing that plot.conf=false is giving errors)?

Comment: what if you just leave it out entirely? What error comes up if you don't include `plot.conf=false`

Comment: Perfect, just modified my answer. Would you mind accepting the new answer?

Comment: Can you click the check mark, should turn green next to the answer